# ASP.NET MVC: How to Detect Browser Width in Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, responsive-design, width, viewport, global-asax

So I have been handed an MVC application, I noticed that the previous developer created two pages of each view, one for Desktop and Tablet Viewing and one for Mobile viewing, my question is is there anyway to get the browser width in Application_Start() so that I can based on that width determine the correct View to load?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Request.Browser` but that data can be outdated. You can use some external service to get new set of devices for example 51degrees.mobi.

For responsive design, you handle things like that on the front end, so you can use jQuery.